# aligning the x-axis labels in a figure using psfrags

Tags: psfrag

I used `laprint` to generate the `.eps` file for my matlab graph. Now the problem is I changed the axis labels to `a,...f` but they dont seem to be aligned w.r.t the horizontal x-axis.
This is the command

`\psfrag{x13}[t][t]{\small a}%` ..where can I change the alignment of `a` w.r.t the axis.

thank you.

Comment: @Dilip: Welcome to tex.sx. Could you please use `\`` to format your inline code and make sure that your question title is properly capitalized. You apparently don't want others to do this for you. Thanks.

Comment: @Martin: thank you for your comments. I dont mind it if others correct me but it would be nice if they do so with a comment of where I was wrong.

Comment: @Dilip: My apologies, I should have added a comment.

Comment: I know you asked for \psfrag, but since you mentioned matlab, it might be worthwhile checking out the matlab2tikz script or, depending on the complexity of your graph, just output a datafile from matlab and do the plotting with pgfplots

Comment: @Dilip: Besides answering your question, we also want to make sure that the page is useful for other users with the same problem. Thus it is normal for other users to edit your post to fix formatting problems, typos and remove distracting text (like “hello” and “thank you”). Please don't see this a personal attack against you, but rather as something like the Wikipedia model.

Comment: @Caramdir: As I am new here I didnt know that..thank you for the info.

Comment: @Dilip: In the same vein as editing to improve the question, I've moved your answer to a comment on Will's answer which is where it seems to belong.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, but I might be mistaken, that [the `matlabfrag` package](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21286-matlabfrag) works around this problem. It was written by a friend of mine to overcome some of `laprint`'s shortcomings.

Its usage is similar to `laprint` but you must size the graphic to your tastes before exporting it to LaTeX.

Comment: can you please tell me what do the [t][t] refer to in the script I put?

Comment: got it..its the position and the postscript text reference point..:)